# Is it possible to have asp:calender show a date from the database?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, calendar

I am trying to have a user type a year into a textbox and if the year exits in the database (which has specific dates for semesters) it displays these dates in a calender.

I have looked for a few days for how to do this but I'm not able to find anything of help.

Is this even possible?  I was hoping to be able to use a SQLDataSource for this but I can't add a connection string to a calender.

Any help would be great!
Mark

*REVISED******
I have a table in my database where it has the start date and end date of each university semester year, e.g. autumn, spring, summer and also the Easter holidays.  I want the user to be able to type the year they wish to change the dates for and hit a search button.  If the database has records for the entered year, a calendar for each date is displayed, selecting the date from the database, not the current date.

Comment: I cant understand ur que.Plz explain in Brief

Comment: Let me get this right, you want a calendar control for each date in your table for the year selected?

Comment: Yea, just so that it saves the user clicking copious times to get to the year they want.

Comment: So if there are 40 dates in your table, you want 40 calendar controls to be displayed?

Comment: No.  I have eight calenders (Autumn start, Autumn end, Spring start, Spring end, Summer start, Summer end, Easter start, Easter end).  These are hidden until the user enters a year that is in the database. Then, these calenders are visible, showing the dates that are in the database.  If the year searched for is not in the database, they can add that year and the calenders will all show Jan 1st of that year.

Comment: ok, what do you have so far? Have you managed to get your dates out of the database? If so can you show your code?

Comment: At the minute I have the calenders that only display when a year that is present in the database.  I can't seem to get the date for any of the start/end dates to even write to a label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out how to do have the date set in the database display in a calender.  Here's the code:

```
        Dim strConn As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\scrummingit2.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT [Year], [Autumn_Start], [Autumn_End], [Spring_Start], [Spring_End], [Summer_Start], [Summer_End], [Easter_Start], [Easter_End] FROM [Semester_Dates] WHERE ([Year] = '" + TxtAddYearDates.Text + "')"

        Dim conn As New SqlConnection(strConn)
        Dim objDR As SqlDataReader
        Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand(Sql, conn)
        conn.Open()
        objDR = Cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        While objDR.Read()

            AutumnStartCalendar.SelectedDate = objDR("Autumn_Start")
            AutumnStartCalendar.VisibleDate = objDR("Autumn_Start")

            AutumnEndCalendar.SelectedDate = objDR("Autumn_End")
            AutumnEndCalendar.VisibleDate = objDR("Autumn_End")

            SpringStartCalendar.SelectedDate = objDR("Spring_Start")
            SpringStartCalendar.VisibleDate = objDR("Spring_Start")

            SpringEndCalendar.SelectedDate = objDR("Spring_End")
            SpringEndCalendar.VisibleDate = objDR("Spring_End")

            SummerStartCalendar.SelectedDate = objDR("Summer_Start")
            SummerStartCalendar.VisibleDate = objDR("Summer_Start")

            SummerEndCalendar.SelectedDate = objDR("Summer_End")
            SummerEndCalendar.VisibleDate = objDR("Summer_End")

            EasterStartCalendar.SelectedDate = objDR("Easter_Start")
            EasterStartCalendar.VisibleDate = objDR("Easter_Start")

            EasterEndCalendar.SelectedDate = objDR("Easter_End")
            EasterEndCalendar.VisibleDate = objDR("Easter_End")


        End While
```